# Input Latitude, Longitude and distance and return sql string filtered by minLat and maxLat and minLong and maxLong

Tags: javascript, sql

So am using an interface called KScript, which is similar to javascript. The purpose is to return an SQL string, that includes lat and long min and max values, so that I can query our database.

Our database consists of records similar to this:

NAME: xy, DATA: xy, LONGITUDE: 53.34, LATIDUDE: 10.03

Now, when the user in the app requests a data record he can put in his current lat and long and drag a distance slider. So I am also giving the script the distance paramater. As a first attempt, I tried just using latitude and simple deducting and adding half of the distance to the latitude. (I know, in reality this is about 100x too much, but just to check).

Now I can definitaly correct this, but i wouldnt know how to account for longitude, as this in effect is now a circle and no longer a straight line.

I tried reading into this, but I dont think much applied to this scenario.

In the end, I need to return an SQL string that basically says:

```
SELECT xyz WHERE latitude >= " +  minLat + " AND latitude <= " + maxLat + " AND
longitude >= " +  minlong+ " AND longitude <= " + maxLong+ "
```

So that I can query our database.

This is my attempt:

```
var distanceLatString = ""
var minLat = 0
var maxLat = 0

if(latitude != 0 ) 
{
    minLat = (latitude - (distance/2))
    maxLat = (latitude + (distance/2))
    distanceLatString = "(latitude >= " +  minLat + " AND latitude <= " + maxLat + ")"
}
```

again, this does give me correct results (even with the distance calculation being incorrect, ofc).

Can someone maybe help me out here?

Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't actually give accurate results, although could be acceptable based on your application needs.   This creates a square around the center point.   Center point to side lines have the proper distance.   Center point to corners are further than your distance parameter.

Comment: Hey, its fine if this isnt a 100% accurate. We take zip codes and convert them into coordinates and that in it self is just an appoximation of the center.

Comment: Good to know, just wanted to point it out to you.   Bit rusty on my math to figure out the circle, but sounds like you'll be OK without it